Box plots in ArcGIS Online
I can't seem to figure out how to get box plots to appear in popups in ArcGIS Online. First, is this even possible? I am trying to find a good way to show summary statistics for four different variables for each county in a state. I can show all the data in text form in the popup, but that's hard to decipher. Having boxplots appear in a popup would be tremendously helpful.
Second, I'm not that good at scripting. I'm using chat gpt to try to help me out. I have a script that validates successfully in both ArcGIS Online and in ArcGIS Pro. Here's the script:
// Define function to create box plot information
function createBoxPlot(mean, median, stddev, iqr, imbalance) {
    var lowerWhisker = median - 1.5 * iqr;
    var upperWhisker = median + 1.5 * iqr;
    var lowerQuartile = median - iqr / 2;
    var upperQuartile = median + iqr / 2;

    return {
        "mean": mean,
        "median": median,
        "lowerWhisker": lowerWhisker,
        "upperWhisker": upperWhisker,
        "lowerQuartile": lowerQuartile,
        "upperQuartile": upperQuartile,
        "stddev": stddev,
        "imbalance": imbalance
    };
}

// Variables for DEM
var dem = createBoxPlot(
    $feature["COUN1_Mean"],
    $feature["COUNT1_MED"],
    $feature["COUNT1_STD"],
    $feature["COUNT1_IQR"],
    $feature["COU1_QIMBL"]
);

// Variables for REP
var rep = createBoxPlot(
    $feature["COUN2_Mean"],
    $feature["COUNT2_MED"],
    $feature["COUNT2_STD"],
    $feature["COUNT2_IQR"],
    $feature["COU2_QIMBL"]
);

// Variables for VAX_ONE_DOSE
var vax = createBoxPlot(
    $feature["COUNT_Mean"],
    $feature["COUNTI_MED"],
    $feature["COUNTI_STD"],
    $feature["COUNTI_IQR"],
    $feature["COUN_QIMBL"]
);

// Variables for Education (Bachelor's Degree or Higher)
var edu = createBoxPlot(
    $feature["ACS_M_Mean"],
    $feature["ACS_MI_MED"],
    $feature["ACS_MI_STD"],
    $feature["ACS_MI_IQR"],
    $feature["ACS__QIMBL"]
);

// Return HTML for box plots
return `
<h4>Box Plots for County Data</h4>
<b>DEM:</b>
<br>Mean: ${dem.mean}, Median: ${dem.median}
<br>Lower Quartile: ${dem.lowerQuartile}, Upper Quartile: ${dem.upperQuartile}
<br>Lower Whisker: ${dem.lowerWhisker}, Upper Whisker: ${dem.upperWhisker}
<br>Standard Deviation: ${dem.stddev}, Quantile Imbalance: ${dem.imbalance}
<hr>
<b>REP:</b>
<br>Mean: ${rep.mean}, Median: ${rep.median}
<br>Lower Quartile: ${rep.lowerQuartile}, Upper Quartile: ${rep.upperQuartile}
<br>Lower Whisker: ${rep.lowerWhisker}, Upper Whisker: ${rep.upperWhisker}
<br>Standard Deviation: ${rep.stddev}, Quantile Imbalance: ${rep.imbalance}
<hr>
<b>VAX_ONE_DOSE:</b>
<br>Mean: ${vax.mean}, Median: ${vax.median}
<br>Lower Quartile: ${vax.lowerQuartile}, Upper Quartile: ${vax.upperQuartile}
<br>Lower Whisker: ${vax.lowerWhisker}, Upper Whisker: ${vax.upperWhisker}
<br>Standard Deviation: ${vax.stddev}, Quantile Imbalance: ${vax.imbalance}
<hr>
<b>Education (Bachelor's Degree or Higher):</b>
<br>Mean: ${edu.mean}, Median: ${edu.median}
<br>Lower Quartile: ${edu.lowerQuartile}, Upper Quartile: ${edu.upperQuartile}
<br>Lower Whisker: ${edu.lowerWhisker}, Upper Whisker: ${edu.upperWhisker}
<br>Standard Deviation: ${edu.stddev}, Quantile Imbalance: ${edu.imbalance}
`;

This will create boxes that list the box plot stats for each county,but will not generate an actual box plot. Am I out of luck? Am I over my head here?

Unfortunately, the HTML support for pop up elements is fairly limited and arcade functions only support generating barcharts, piecharts, or scatter in Mapviewer pop ups.

To compliment @AustinAverill comment, here is the page that lists all the chart types support by AGOL.
